# a-frame how to use several gltf

Tags: aframe, webvr

I want to show 50 trees in different positions, but doing so takes 3 minutes to load and the browser does not respond for a few seconds

```
<a-entity position="-11.39987 0.07117 -83.67416" scale="0.02 0.01 0.01" gltf-model="#tree"></a-entity>
<a-entity position="15.54987 0.07117 -83.67416" scale="0.02 0.01 0.01" gltf-model="#tree"  ></a-entity>
<a-entity position="-11.39987 0.07117 -100.67416" scale="0.07 0.03 0.03" gltf-model="#tree" ></a-entity>
```

I'm new to this, will there be another way to load the same model in different positions?. I want to add more models but with this problem I can't do it at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load a single model, and then create a custom component, that will create an array of new entities, and you can create the gltf-model component on each of the new entities, and this effectively makes instances of the original. You can then create other components, position, rotation, material, etc and vary the parameters inside.

[Here is a glitch](https://glitch.com/~tree-grove)

Comment: thank you very much it worked for me, but when you open it in the browser of the oculus the screen goes black and restarts, apparently it does not support loading everything

Comment: I updated the glitch so that the array of trees are created after the 'model-loaded' event occurs, and this may solve the problem.

Comment: the same thing continues, I realize that it loads 2 but then the system does not respond and reboots

Comment: I apologize, I don't have oculus, so I don't know exactly why it does that. I would listen for an event that indicates that the occulus is ready before proceeding.

Comment: thank you very much and sorry for the inconvenience